# Jquery - Header banner rotator

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Can anybody recommend a decent cross-browser jquery banner rotator that I can use to dynamically fade between click-able banners?

Thanks for your help
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery Cycle. You can create paged banners with navigation and it takes 2 minutes to get it working.

There are loads of settings for effects and lots more.

Here is a demo:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager-over.html

More demos here too: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/more.html

Comment: Glad it helped. I needed this a few weeks ago and it seemed perfect for my solution too :)

Answer (score 0):

How about [Shuffle, a jQuery banner rotator plugin featuring multiple transitions](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/shuffle)?